# Antisymmetric tensor

Tags: tensors

Why is an antisymmetric tensor of rank (0,2) always traceles?? I see it for the cases where the tensor is, let's say, a general tensor. BUT, if we assume the tensor is a metric:
$$\operatorname{tr}(g) = g^{vu}g_{uv} = \delta^{u}_{u} = N$$
Is not this true? (N is the dimension of the space)

Comment: Metric tensors have to be symmetric & nonzero (indeed, invertible).

Comment: Oh that's true, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an anti symmetric rank two tensor is: $T_{i,j}=-T_{j,i}$.
If $i=j$ then $T_{i,i}=-T_{i,i}=0$. The trace is the summation over $T_{i,i}$ which would all be zero.